# has_many through fetching related values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best way to extract the related data from a has many through relationship?

If my tasks and categories are joined through categorizations, I'd like to display a list of tasks and their related categories in my index view.

I've tried putting the following in my controller:

```
@tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => :taskcategories )
```

However that fails.

In my view, I tried this:

```
<% for task in @tasks %>

<li><%= task.title %> <%= task.taskcategory_name %></li>

<% end %>
```

That also fails.

Comment: What are the exact names of your models? (i.e. is it `Task` and `Category`, or is it `Task` and `Taskcategory`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your association definitions are right, you can just:

```
@tasks = Task.find(:all, :include => :categories)
```

... and within the view:

```
<% for task in @tasks %>
  <li><%= task.title %> <%= task.categories.map{|c| c.name}.join(', ') %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really very helpful. It was the last bit I couldn't work out - where on earth can I read more about this?! Jx